# getting article text using xpath but omit some tags

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to parse (article) text only using xpath.

I want to get all text which are direct children and all nested descendants text of a node, except for the following nodes/tags: `<script>, <ul class="pager pagenav">, <style>`.

Example html to match using xpath:

```
<section class="entry-content">
    want this article text
    <script>dont want this</script>
    more text i want
    <p>want this text too</p>
    <any>also this</any>
    <style>dont want this either</style>
    <ul class="pager pagenav">nope, dont want this <a>Prev Next</a></ul>
</section>
```

Currently, i have something like:

```
    result = tree.xpath('//section[@class="entry-content"]/*[not(descendant-or-self::script or self::ul[@class="pager pagenav"] or self::style)]/../descendant-or-self::text()')
```

..but it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`child::node()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) to match both regular children and text child nodes:

> `child::node()` selects all the children of the context node, whatever their node type

`self::` would help to filter unwanted elements having specific names:

```
//section[@class="entry-content"]/child::node()[not(self::script or self::ul or self::style)]/descendant-or-self::text()
```